# Javascript ParseInt() not working in Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, parseint

I have a small java script that basically picks up whatever the user has entered into a form and sends it as JSON to a servlet that does some stuff. It's sort of a "preview" function before they submit the form itself. The script works in Chrome, however Firefox does not correctly parse a hidden div I have in the page that tells the JS how many fields of the form there are.

The JS

```
function send_formdata() {
    var numGenes = parseInt(document.getElementById("numGenes").textContent);
    alert(numGenes);
    var jsonObj = [];
    for (var i = 0; i <numGenes; i++) {
        if (document.getElementById("c"+i).value == "") {
            alert("Please fill out all fields before checking tax model.");
            return;
        }
    jsonObj.push({"value" : document.getElementById("c"+i).value})
    }
```

....

I added the alert() as a debug. In chrome, the alert reads "25" in Firefox it reads "NaN".

The part of the page being picked up:

```
<div id="numGenes" style="display: none">25</div>
```

Any Ideas on why Firefox doesn't work here? It's not erroring out, the script simply ends up sending an empty array to the server.

Comment: What does `document.getElementById("numGenes").textContent` get you in Firefox?

Comment: When I try your code it works fine. ParseInt displays 25 in FireFox.

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass `radix` as a second parameter. [Click here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt) to see the documentation.

You should use it like this:

`var numGenes = parseInt(document.getElementById("numGenes").textContent, 10);`

Answer (score 0):

The code as shown above is missing a single "}" at the end to correctly close off the function.  Otherwise, it works in Firefox - displays the value in the .  The subsequent document.getElementId() fails, but I assume you have DOM elements with id's c0, c1, etc.

Comment: I truncated the function prematurely, there are some bits afterward that send the JSON object to a servlet. It's interesting that it's working for you. I wonder if it might be having trouble finding it in the context of the entire page?